# read arabic characters from text files in PHP

Tags: php, text, arabic

I want to read arabic characters from to text file and show them
but they are shown in a strange symbols like �
and they can't be compared with any characters

Comment: are those texts in UTF-8? try to do `utf8_encode($text)` where `$text` is your Arabic text.. and see if it works..

Comment: Please more details, how read ? how output ? what encoding ?

Comment: how about the header encoding? (meta charset)

Comment: <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
read using$str1= $str1 . fgets($file1). "<br />";

Comment: words in text file are:
الاحتجاجات
@khadijame:
‎#Ikhwan
#EgyStudents

the output of all arabic letters is �

Comment: you may check the encoding of your text file. notepad++ for example often use ASCII as default. change the encoding to proper utf-8. maybe this works. the header seems to me to be right.

Answer (score 1):

Let try to work on it together  :

I will assume you code looks like :

1- your file should  written in UTF8 encoding , i will take care if it's not

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <?php
    $file_path = "c:/home/user/text.txt";
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    // if its utf8 file skip this line 
    $arabic_data = iconv("windows-1256" , "utf8" , $data);

    echo $arabic_data ; ?>
```

in case you are linux user you can use `iconv` in commandline `much powerful & easier`

I'll update my answer in case you need more help or provide more info

Answer (score 0):

Try to create .htaccess file in the root of your web application and write such string there `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the encoding of these files. Can be UTF-8, can be some transliteracion, can be something else. Then you have to convert to UTF-8 (not needed if are already utf-8), then you output that as in the page,... having the page declare itself as UTF-8... Like the Mira comment.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

Answer (score 0):

<`meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />`

is life saver

if you working with php, use

`echo '<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />';`

in you scrip

Answer (score 0):

Change file encoding to UTF-8
By open file by using any editor and change encode from editor to utf-8